# Test System.Web.Authorization From Code

Tags: asp.net

Inside a web.config file, you can control user/role authorization like this:

```
 <location path="MyPage.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="User1"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

An asp.net menu will automatically filter out pages that aren't authorized for the current user, but **how can I check in my code if they have the correct permissions?**

I'd like to disable or hide links that they don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

There's no in-built method to test permissions as such, you have to retrieve the current identity using:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

...and test this against the respective criteria. A better approach might be to assign roles and use this method to test permission sets:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Managers")
```

You could also programmatically access the authorization section:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
AuthorizationSection asection;
asection = config.GetSection("system.web/authorization") as AuthorizationSection;
```

...but you'd need to implement a means to test these rules against a particular resource demand.